# How is React Native multiple data input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

My English is not very good, sorry for that. There is a structure that I want to make multiple data entries. I will add separate json lines for each input. But I can add once from the same line. But I want to create a separate json data for each input. I am sharing the sample code. It doesn't work that way because it constantly updates the previous data in.

```
var families = [];

for(let i = 0; i < formStep + 1; i++) {
    families.push(
        <View key={i}>
            <View>
                <Text style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>T.C</Text>
                <Input
                    placeholder='Lütfen T.C belirtin'
                    style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}                            
                    onChangeText={(input) => this.setState(prevState => ({                          
                        formData: [...prevState.formData, {tc: input}]
                    }))}
                />
            </View>

            <View>
                <Text style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>İsim</Text>
                <Input
                    placeholder='Lütfen ad ve soyad belirtin'
                    style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
                />
            </View>

            <View>
                <Text style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>Meslek</Text>
                <Input
                    placeholder='Lütfen meslek belirtin'
                    style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
                />
            </View>
            {(formStep > 0) ? <Divider style={{marginBottom: 15, marginTop: 10}}></Divider> : null}
        </View>
    )
}
```

working input onChangeText method;

```
Array [
  Object {
    "tc": "0",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "tc": "0",
  },
  Object {
    "tc": "00",
  },
]
Array [
  Object {
    "tc": "0",
  },
  Object {
    "tc": "00",
  },
  Object {
    "tc": "000",
  },
]
```

But I want;

```
Array [
  Object {
    "tc": "000",
  },
]
```

And then if there is more than one input;

```
Array [
  Object {
    "tc": "000",
  },
  Object {
    "tc": "111",
  },
  Object {
    "tc": "222",
  },
]
```

I hope I could tell. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you just need to overwrite the field you want to update this way:

```
onChangeText={(input) => this.setState(prevState => ({                          
    formData: [...prevState.formData.tc, {tc: input}]
}))}
```

And for the other inputs, it would look something like this:

```
onChangeText={(input) => this.setState(prevState => ({                          
    formData: [...prevState.formData.exemple, {exemple: input}]
}))}
```

You can also group input changes in one function:

```
updateText = (key, value) => {
    // Merge the old key, or set it
    this.setState(currentState => ({ 
        formData: [
            ...currentState.formData,
            [key]: value
        ]
    }));
};
```

And you use it that way:

```
onChangeText={text => this.updateText("tc", text)}
```

Comment: I try but get this error; TypeError Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: Thank you Pierre but visual code get this warning ',' expected. for [key]: value line

Comment: by the way, only key is coming not set value to key.

Comment: Also json data input is always going on I want it to overwrite.